# MySQL Select the Number of Entries that Occur "N" times

Tags: sql, mysql

I've collected a number of entries in a table for a sweepstakes. I've been asked by the client to provide:

- The number of unique entries
- The number of entries that occur twice.
- The number of entries that occur three times.

I'm able to determine the number of unique entries, but not sure how to pull out the number of entries that occur a specific number of times. I tried something like this:

SELECT email, count(email) AS NumberOfEntries
FROM entries
GROUP BY NumberOfEntries

That gives the error: Can't group on 'NumberOfEntries'

I'm hoping to see something like this:
NumberOfEntries / Total
1 / 1,000 (Meaning 1,000 people entered once and only once)
2 / 1,300 (Meaning 1,300 people entered exactly twice)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
SELECT numberOfEntries, count(*) FROM (
  SELECT email, count(*) AS numberOfEntries
    FROM entries
   GROUP BY email
)
GROUP BY numberOfEntries
```

You can add `HAVING` clause to inner select to restrict counts for number of entries returned to 1,2,3 or whatever else.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
SELECT email, count(email) as NumberOfEntries
FROM entries
GROUP BY email
```

will give you a list of email and number of entries (the GROUP BY should list all non-aggregate columns). If you want to limit the selection to only those emails with 2 or 3 entries you need to use a having clause.

```
SELECT email, count(email) as NumberOfEntries
FROM entries
GROUP BY email
HAVING NumberOfEntries = 2
```

Or, to get a count of the number of each entry, you can wrap that in another query like:

```
SELECT NumberOfEntries, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfEmails
FROM (SELECT email, count(email) as NumberOfEntries
    FROM entries
    GROUP BY email) AS x
GROUP BY NumberOfEntries
ORDER BY NumberOfEntries ASC
```

This should give you number of entries, and a count of how many people have that number of entries (listed from 1 entry up)